# AWS Glue Job bookmark value modification for JDBC sources

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, mssql-jdbc

Glue provides job bookmark feature to load data incrementally  using the column we are providing or using primary key column if column is not provided manually. I have a scenario where I want to load data from SQL Server till a particular point of time even though data is available beyond that point. Is there a way to use custom queries to load data or to update job bookmark value I want.